# How to find duplicate between oracle rows on mutiple columns?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables in oracle. I need to find duplicates on mutiple columns on them. It should not consider null values as duplicate in any of them. What I want to achieve is result in a single row, such that I get the first user as ExistingUser asn every record that matches to it in terms of Name, Phone Or Adress as MatchingUsers column.

I have one user with NAME=MAX ZANEO who has a Phone=123 and ADDRESS=SesameStreet. And then orderd by ID ,i have two more users after that in the table, with NAME=NODD A who has a Phone=123 and ADDRESS= Wall Street. and with NAME=NODD B who has a Phone=345 and ADDRESS= SesameStreet. Then , I want result in such a way that would give data in the folowing way (Bold is column header,italics is column data) : **ExistingUser**=*MAX ZANEO*,**MatchingUsers**=*NODD A,NODD B*,**MatchingData**=*Phone,Address*.

Below is the query for the source of data.

```
  select
   up.ID
   , ( up.FirstName || ' ' || up.LastName ) as FullName
   , up.Phone
   , up.Email
   , uph.Address
   From
   UserProfile up
   Left Join
   UserProfileHistory uph
  on up.ID =  uph.UserProfileId
   Order by up.Created
```

[Image of Result data of the query above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0eUD.png)

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you provide some examples of duplicates and some example of special duplicates(with nulls but considered duplicates by you requirements). I your example are there duplicates?

Comment: Florin, Have you checked the image along with question? I hope you might get some idea from it.

Comment: @FlorinGhita  In this result,suppose I have one user with **NAME=MAX ZANEO** who has a **Phone=123** and **ADDRESS=SesameStreet**. And then orderd by ID ,i have two more users after that in the table, with **NAME=NODD A** who has a **Phone=123** and **ADDRESS= Wall Street**. and with **NAME=NODD B** who has a **Phone=345** and **ADDRESS= SesameStreet**. Then , I want result in such a way that would give data in the folowing way (Bold is column header,italics is column data) : **ExistingUser**=_MAX ZANEO_,**MatchingUsers**=_NODD A,NODD B_,**MatchingData**=_Phone,Address_. Hope that explains it.

Comment: Please post formatted text rather than images, and edit your question to add more information rather than trying to explain in comments. It would be useful to show sample data you are trying to compare with various scenarios, and the result you want - again as formatted text.

Comment: @AlexPoole , a newbie so new to formatting. I am stuck on this problem though and need solution urgently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: The problem is too heavy. You want to find similar rows, but conditions are too lax. You have some quality problems in your database or just want to group users with some same attributes?

Comment: Are ID and Phone number unique in your data?

Comment: Yes they are. Only these are non repeating in my data. Is there some way I can use them to find duplicates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ID and Phone number are unique in your data, use self join and then you can use their sum as a unique value. Those rows having the exact same sum for both will be similar and duplicate.

```
 a.Id + b.Id + TO_NUMBER(regexp_replace(a.Phone, '[^[:digit:]]', '')) + TO_NUMBER(regexp_replace(b.Phone, '[^[:digit:]]', '')) as UniqueSum
```

Then use this result in a temporary table and calculate row numbers over them like

```
row_number() over(partition by  UniqueSum order by Created ) as RowNumber
```

then pick the topmost row like:

```
 where RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Great idea. This worked. Why did I not think about this. Thanks